# Trouble using pywrap

Tags: python

I have installed wxPython and am able to execute some scripts from Robin's great book. I am able to open pyCrust too. But if I try to wrap a wx script with pywrap, I get this -

> Blockquote
>   PS C:\Users\jf7366\Documents\PythonScripts\wxpython> pywrap Flintstonize.py
>   pywrap : The term 'pywrap' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + pywrap Flintstonize.py

I tried installing pywrap by itself, successful install, but to no avail... Why would I have a PATH issue with pywrap but not PyCrust? This makes no sense to me obviously.

Regards,

Jack

Answer (score 1):

It's more likely that pywrap needs the PATH, but PyCrust most probably does not, so the best solution would be to add Python To PATH.

Comment: I am able to type python in a shell anywhere in the directory structure and get python. I can see the Anaconda2 directory in the path where the python.exe is. So I don't think this is the problem...